# How can I fix a broken "off" switch on a sump pump after overheating?

Tags: sump-pump

We have a sump pump in our basement. It uses a float switch to turn on when the basin its in fills with water.

We recently ran into an issue where it didn't turn off while we were out (float switch stuck), so came home to the motor sounding horrible and it overheating. Immediately unplugged it and dumped a bunch of cold water into the basin to cool it down, since the pump itself was extremely hot and smelled like something was burning.

Ever since then, we have not been able to get it to turn off. As soon as we plug it in, the pump starts up regardless of float switch placement. The float switch itself appears fine, and we can hear a "click" when we flip it up or down, but the pump does not turn off.

Can overheating a sump pump cause this kind of failure in the on/off switch? And if so, is it something easy to fix, or would it be best to hire a professional or just get a new pump?

I don't know the exact model number until we unhook all the pipes to remove and clean it off (maybe after work today), however it is a small pump from Wayne Water Systems that looks very similar to [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00554SP3K)

Comment: The float switch is what tells the pump to turn on/off. If the pump stays on, then either the switch is bad or connected incorrectly.

Comment: exactly hearing a click means nothing, (something could have come loose. That it doesn't switch of as a result of the click is much more meaningfull

Comment: Thank you, we will try taking apart the switch and investigating it further. Maybe worst case scenario we'll buy a piggyback float switch for it.